# SQL Summing a subquery

Tags: sql, subquery, aggregate

I am trying to sum a subquery , but don't know how to rewrite this:

```
FORMAT(
SUM(
   CASE WHEN SOH.LASDLVNUM_0 <> '' 
           AND SOH.LASINVNUM_0 <> '' 
           AND MONTH(SOH.SHIDAT_0) = MONTH(GETDATE()) 
        THEN 
           (Select (SID.NETPRI_0) 
            from x3v6.CICPROD.SINVOICED SID 
            where SID.NUM_0 = SOH.LASINVNUM_0 
              and SID.ITMREF_0 = SOQ.ITMREF_0 
              and SID.STOFCY_0 = SOQ.STOFCY_0) 
          * SOQ.INVQTY_0 * SOH.CHGRAT_0 
        ELSE 0.00 END), 
       '##,##0.00') as 'Invoiced (MTD)',
```

to not get the error message "Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery."

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? That is non-standard syntax.

Comment: You cannot put a subquery inside of a case statement.  Show the entire SQL query, and we can fix it.

Comment: @CharlesBretana at least in sql-server you can definitely put a sub query inside of a case expression, I just tested to make sure.  not that I would necessarily recommend it though

Comment: You can't have a subquery inside an aggragate function -- that is what the error says.  lets see your whole query if you want us to fix it -- there is no fix from here.

Comment: So the problem isn't the fact that you are using a subquery the problem is that it is in the aggregate function as Hogan says, I just tested that case and it will give that error

Comment: @Matt and all he has to do is pull out the sub-query into a CTE and join to it -- my guess.  (can probably do the sum in the CTE too)

Comment: @Hogan my guess too.  I was going to suggest cross/outer apply as I suspect that could work too but I still have yet to test.  Or for that matter just join the tables and manipulate from the joins.

Comment: @Matt -- I'm amused that we are enjoying solving the problem without actually seeing the code.

Comment: @Matt,  Thanks for the clarification. I did not know you could do that. Although, as you said, not that I'd want to

Answer (score 0):

I got curious because I had never tried to SUM a subquery.  I wouldn't advise it but I try to stay away from subqueries that are applied per row (e.g. column definition) when I can.  Anyway, you can either figure out how to solve with joins our you can move your case expression to an OUTER APPLY and some that which essentially lets you aggregate a subquery.....

```
DECLARE @Table AS TABLE (Id INT IDENTITY(1,1), Criteria INT, Criteria2 INT)
DECLARE @OtherTable AS TABLE (TID INT)
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES (1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(4,4)
INSERT INTO @OtherTable  VALUES (1),(1),(2),(2),(3),(3),(4),(4)

SELECT
    t.Id
    ,SUM(COALESCE(oa.Value,0))
FROM
    @Table t
    OUTER APPLY (SELECT
                TID as Value
             FROM
                @OtherTable ot
             WHERE
                ot.TID = t.Id
                AND t.Criteria  % 2 = 0
                AND t.Criteria2 % 2 = 0) oa
GROUP BY
    t.Id
```

Note when you use this method the trick is the WHEN condition gets added to the your WHERE condition of the sub query in the OUTER APPLY

Also I have assumed SQL-SERVER due to your use of FORMAT()